# What're the differences between use and import dependencies?

Tags: java, uml, package-diagram

I'm a bit confused about the differences between `use` and `import` dependencies in the package diagrams in UML modelling the java program.

My guess is that when the dependency `import` is used, the classes in the package being imported are used to instantiate objects in the importing package. When the dependency '`use`' is used, the object or attributes or methods in the class of the package being imported are used in the importing package. Whichever dependency I use, I need to write:

```
public import...
```

in the code. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the `use` dependency indicates that a model element - not necessarily a package - requires another model element for its implementation (see [here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html#usage) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_(UML))), whereas the `import` dependency is more specific to a package and indicates that the importing package's namespace is amended by the imported package (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_diagram)).

However, you were asking for the use of both of the dependencies in a package diagram: In this case, I would interpret the `use` dependency as a looser coupling (e.g. package A just "uses" something from package B). In contrast, the `import` dependency specifically refers to each element of the imported package with an impact on the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The difference from a language view is that in the `use` case you just pick certain parts from a package while the `import` takes all. Most programming languages take imported packages into their scope so you address elements from the package as being part of the importing itself. For the `use`d ones you usually qualify the namespace.